# Sort (hex) colors by Hue

Tags: ruby

I have a list of colors represented in hex. And I would like to sort them by Hue.Small example:

```
My_hash = {"1"=>["#00050c"], 
 "2"=>["#ffffff"], 
 "3"=>["#d6e7ff"],
 "4"=>["#008000"],
 "5"=>["#0768ef"],
 "6"=>["#07408e"],
 "7"=>["#42AAFF"],
 "8"=>["#21406b"],
 "9"=>["#032656"]}
My_hash.each_value {|value| puts value}
```

Comment: Your data format looks a bit weird. It could be a plain array of strings. What did you try? Did you take a look at https://github.com/halostatue/ ?

Comment: Yes,i tried to use it, but  i don't know how to apply this with HEX

Comment: That hex value, what "encoding" does it represent? RGB?

Comment: Sorting is not a problem. You need to find out how to get the hue value from those strings. If those are rgb, then you could use rgb->hsv transformation.

Comment: You were recommended a color transformation lib a day ago. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/816924/178828 Any progress there?

Comment: Yes, i tried it too, but i have started to study ruby,and i want to know other options

Comment: @Маратон: you'll get better answers/help if you actually respond to questions in comments.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: _"I would like to sort them by Hue"_ – how do you determine the hue? Do you have a method for that or a 3rd party library?

Comment: @Stefan: those strings might be in hsv/hsl (in which case, lexicographic sorting _also_ sorts by hue). But we have no idea if it's the case.

Comment: I dont have time to follow everything. At this lib, there is a transform into HSL. But i want to do this without this lib

Comment: Oh, you don't have time. That's interesting. Well, have fun with investigating color transformation math. The conversion algorithm is easily googlable.

Comment: I already did it,thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this updated example also we don't care about hash, we'll just deal with an arrays of hex colors:

```
require 'paint'

#intantiate web_colors from gist and shuffle them
eval(`curl https://gist.githubusercontent.com/lacostenycoder/394341d3c63589a050d72b8d9ae529aa/raw/4a11cd6ca81e07a643e5f3481e38494ff3c9b973/web_colors_shuffle.rb`)

def hex_to_rgb(hex)
  h = hex.gsub("#","")
  /(?<r>..)(?<g>..)(?<b>..)/ =~ h
  [r,g,b].map {|cs| cs.to_i(16)}
end

def rgb_to_hsl(r,g,b, by_hue=false)
  # normalize r, g and b
  r /= 255.0
  g /= 255.0
  b /= 255.0

  c_min = [r,g,b].min
  c_max = [r,g,b].max

  h = s = l = (c_min + c_max) / 2

  d = (c_max - c_min)#.to_f

  # compute hue
  if c_max == c_min
    h = s = 0.0 # achromatic i.e. ffffff or 000000
  else
    s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - c_max - c_min) : d / (c_max + c_min);
    h = (g - b) / d + ( g < b ? 6 : 0) if c_max == r
    h = (b - r) / d + 2 if c_max == g if c_max == g
    h = (r - g) / d + 4 if c_max == b if c_max == b
  end
  h /= 6
  by_hue ? h : [h, s, l]
end

def sort_em(colors, by_hue=false)
  colors.sort_by { |color| rgb_to_hsl(*hex_to_rgb(color), by_hue) }
end

def puts_em(colors)
  colors.each{|color| puts Paint[color, color]}
end

#shuffled web_colors sorted by hue
puts "\nShuffled web_colors by hue \n\n"
puts_em(sort_em @shuffled, by_hue=true)

puts "Shuffled web_colors by HSL \n\n"
#shuffled web_colors sorted by HLS
puts_em(@shuffled)

# sample uniformly at random from RGB space
colors = 200.times.map {  (0..255).to_a.sample(3).map { |i| i.to_s(16).rjust(2, '0')}.join   }

puts "\n Shuffled Random By Hue\n\n"
puts_em(sort_em colors, by_hue=true)

puts "\nShuffled Random by HSL\n\n"
puts_em(sort_em colors)
```

You may need to first run `gem install paint` and you can [download gist](https://gist.github.com/lacostenycoder/394341d3c63589a050d72b8d9ae529aa) of this

Comment: Yeap,it works, and works also what you deleted)Thanks.

Comment: This obviously does not work, since `"c0" > "C5" && "c0" < "c5" #⇒ true`. You need at least `map(&:downcase)` there.

Comment: @mudasobwa Would you help giving another downvote? Mine alone does not seem to be sufficient.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks, I've updated my answer. good catch.

Comment: hey guys thanks for the feedback, I updated my answer, please remove down votes if this solves the problem correctly. thanks.

Comment: @lacostenycoder: Much better. You should still test it though. I think your `hex_to_rgb` is broken when html input has a leading `#`.

Comment: @EricDuminil I tested and got no error and it returned expected array when run with `hex_to_rgb('#07408e')` see http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/baeb6

Comment: "No exception" doesn't mean "no error".  `hex_to_rgb('#07408e')` returns `[0, 116, 8] ` Which is clearly wrong : red channel should be `7`, not `0`. You could use another program (e.g. GIMP) to check if the RGB values and hue are correct.

Comment: @EricDuminil updated again

Comment: @lacostenycoder: A few notes : your code is mutating @hash. It's probably not the desired behaviour. You should mention which gem you're using. Please don't use `eval(curl)`, we shouldn't have to trust you and go look at the gist before running the code.

Comment: @EricDuminil Not sure what you meant by mutating at hash. The only reason for the curl is because I didn't want to past a huge array into Stackoverflow which is all that code is doing.  I agree it's not best practice. What is in this case?  Thanks

Comment: Compare `@shuffled` at the beginning and at the end of your script. It's been modified by `gsub!`.

Comment: @EricDuminil good catch. fixed it. What about ideas on large array instead of curling?

Comment: @lacostenycoder: It would be fine to have one huge line instead IMHO.

Comment: Finally, you don't need to show different updates for the code you've written. There's an history link just for that purpose. Pick the best alternative and show it.
SO can be frustrating sometimes, especially on low quality questions such as this one. Keep up the good work!

Comment: @mudasobwa: This answer got much better.

Comment: @sawa: This answer got much better.